# Select Top 2 Dates Access DB

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Hello I'm working with a home grown training database that I'm trying to pull the top two dates from in a query.
I've looked at other posts and have had no luck.  I've created a temp table that has the set of records I want to pull from.  The Table lists all the different training from all employees and their test date.  I need to pull the two most recent test dates for each specific training.  Each training has a specific id even if it is the same training just a different year.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

The table `tbl_TEMP` has the fields:

```
Subdepartment
last_name
first_name
employee_id
id
training
test_date
revision
expiration_date
status
```

Comment: Is your question about MySQL or MS-Access? They're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This selects the 2 most recent dates

```
SELECT TOP 2 TestDate
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT TestDate FROM temp)
ORDER BY TestDate DESC;
```

From your comment, I understand that you don't want only the dates, but all the records with these dates. So use the dates query for an `IN (subquery)` where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE
    TestDate IN (
        SELECT TOP 2 TestDate
        FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT TestDate FROM temp)
        ORDER BY TestDate DESC;
    )
```

Comment: The table has over 4k records and when use this I only get 1 record returned. SELECT TOP 2  [tbl_TEMP.Test Date] 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT [tbl_TEMP.Test Date] from tbl_TEMP); The database is in an Access 2000 file format if that makes any differece.  I added the ORDER BY section that I forgot and only got 2 records back.

Comment: Just tried Oliver's suggestion and the query executes but I only get 6 records.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how your table looks and how many records are supposed to be returned. Is it possible that the column does not only store the date but also a time?

Comment: The table has the following fields: Subdepartment, last_name, first_name, employee_id, id, training, test_date, revision, expiration_date, status.  The test date is a date/time data type but only the date is in the field itself.  This table is a temp one that I created from a query because the test date was a calculated field.  Hope this helps.  Thanks

Comment: I still do not understand why you say that not enough records are returned. If the first query returns two records (i.e. the two most recent dates), then the second query will return all records for those dates.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't do a good job of explaining.  I need the two most recent dates for each test taken by each employee.  The table contains all tests taken by every employee.  Some of the tests are duplicates as they have to be retaken every year or two. So I'm looking to pull the 2 most recent dates for each unique test per employee.  Thank you and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: how can a test be identified (since it has to be unique)? I don't see any test_id field. And what is the primary key of your table? You shoud really show your table structure as [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statement. This would make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

To select the most recent dates open a new query, go to SQL view and write something like this:

SELECT TOP 2 Table1.Daterc, Table1.training
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Daterc, Table1.training
ORDER BY Table1.Daterc DESC;

Where "Table1" is the name of your table, "Daterc" is the date column and "training" is the training column. If the dates are unique you won´t need the GROP BY sentence. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Query Executes but only get 6 records.  I must be missing something but I will keep trying.  Thanks

Comment: You will have to create a series of querys, each one with the previous sentence adding: WHERE Table1.training = "TrainingX" ("TrainingX beeing each of the trainings available in the data) After each one of these querys create another one that appends the resulting records (The 2 top dates of each training) to a Table. Put all this on a Macro and run it. I hope this solves the problem.